# Senchatouch localstorage and phonegap

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, local-storage

I'm playing with Senchatouch and I notice sniffing on Chrome 'Options' -> 'Under the Hood' -> 'Cookies and other data' that any localstorage created on Sencha Touch has null 'Origin'.

This is not a real problem since everything works perfectly and any localstorage has its own id. 
But what if I embed this app with phonegap and deploy on a device? If I have two different apps and both have null 'origin' they will share all localstorage! And who can grantee they don't share a localstorage id?

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per HTML5 draft spec, browsers isolate LocalStorage values based on scheme + hostname + unique port (also known as an HTML5 Origin).Hostname is expected, since we don't want malicious websites to have access to other websites' LocalStorage data.

So, I think for your case also the data should be stored in domain name. Do check Chrome's Developer tools->Resources tab.

Comment: Thx. The problem is an application embedded in phonegap the following origin: (h t t p://localhost/), so every app on device build with phonegap has the same origin! Guess if I name a localstorage with the same name of someone else!!!

Comment: No, for phonegap the localstorage is handled by OS webkit and it maintains unique localstorage for each app. So, do not worry about mixing data and just go on using localstorage with phonegap.